# Pass closeModal from one component to other with react

Tags: reactjs

Hi i am trying to close a modal box from another component. I have a component with a list and other with a form.

The error that i get is:

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this2.closeModal is not a function**

The List file with the modal commands has:

```js
closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

render() {
    const { closeModal } = this.state

...
            <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Adicionar / Editar</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <CategoryForm 
                id={this.state.id || null}
                closeModal={closeModal}
                />
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                  Close
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            </>
// some code

    }
```

the file with form, that will close the modal after saving info in the database is

```
class CategoryForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      closeModal: props.closeModal
    }    
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let category = {
      title: this.state.category.title,
    }
    Api.saveCategory(category, this.state.category.id)
      .then(response => {
        const [error, errors] = response
        if (error) {
          this.setState({
            errors: errors
          })
        } else {  
          this.setState(
            this.closeModal()
          ) 
        }
      })      
  }

//some code

render() {

              <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="title">Title</Label>
                  <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={category.title} placeholder="Enter title" onChange={this.setTitle} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="slug">Slug</Label>
                  <Input type="text" name="slug" id="slug" value={category.slug} placeholder="Enter slug" onChange={this.setSlug} />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button color="success">Submit</Button>
              </Form>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the list file create a command that call the function close modal:

```
closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

addCategory() {
    this.closeModal()
}

render() {

...
            <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Adicionar / Editar</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <CategoryForm 
                id={this.state.id || null}
                addCategory={this.addCategory}
                />
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                  Close
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            </>
// some code

    }
```

In the form, props the function at the handleSubmit:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let category = {
      title: this.state.category.title,
      slug: this.state.category.slug,
    }

    Api.saveCategory(category, this.state.category.id)
      .then(response => {
        const [error, errors] = response
        if (error) {
          this.setState({
            errors: errors
          })
        } else {  
          this.setState(
          ) 
        }
      })
    const form = event.target;
    this.props.addCategory( id, slug, title);
    form.reset();
      
  }
```